# How to convert large XML to string in java

Tags: java, xml, apache-pig, dom4j

As a part of PIG script, I need to get the XML that is generated using a UDF and the XML is too large (around a 1.5GB). Currently I am using below code to convert XML to String

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XMLWriter output = new XMLWriter(sw, xmlFormat);
    try {
       output.write(document);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    return sw.toString();
```

This throws OutofMemoryError as the StringWriter is using string buffer internally and it depends on Arrays.As Arrays uses integer for index and the length of XML is beyond the int range.

Is there a way to convert this large xml to String and send it back to pig script? or can we achieve it in any other way.

FYI - we are using dom4j(`org.dom4j.Document`) for handling XMLs

**Update1:**
 I tried below code with which I am now able to store 800 MB but still the file which is of 1.5 GB is failing

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        XMLWriter output = new XMLWriter(result, xmlFormat);
        output.write(document);
        output.close();
        return result.toString("UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: AFAIK XML is already a text-based format, so it is already actually a String. Also I don't know why exactly you want to convert it to String, maybe the problem lies on your reasoning. In any case, you could either: 1) allocate more memory to the JVM or 2) use a file instead of a String for transfer, then read it on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid running out of memory, you need to stream your xml file. You can use for that the [StreamingXMLLoader](http://help.mortardata.com/technologies/pig/xml#toc_0LoadingXMLDatawithStreamingXMLLoader) that stream and parse your xml directly in your Pig script.